# How do you send data from Volley onResponse to ViewPager Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-volley

I am building an app, in which the i call a serviceIntent from the MainActivity. Using eventbus, the service then calls an event when the data is ready. I am currently subscribing to the event in the fragment that hosts the viewpager, however after that, how do I pass that data to the fragments inside the viewpager?

does someone have some sample code of viewpager http call or could help up with the design pattern to implement here.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is

```
youractivity.yourfragmentinstance.yourmethodinfragment(response);
```

other way is interfaces